# Asp.net Custom Table Cell ClientID not set

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, clientid, asp.net-customcontrol

I have a class derived from WebControls.TableCell. 
When the Text property is set, I call a method that dynamically adds asp:Panels and asp:LiteralControls to the Cell. I want to reference these controls in Javascript, so naturally I tried using the ClientId of the panels in my JS functions. However, these controls have no ClientId set (the string is empty). Why is this? How do I force the ClientIds to be set?

As a temporary solution, I set the ClientIDMode to "static" and created the IDs on my own, but this is not satisfactory because it's hard to reference those IDs in JS. Why? If you assign, for example, "12345" to one control, it gets changed on client side to something like "MainContent_123456". This is bad because the "MainContent" part is not fixed; thus I never know for sure what the real Id on the client side will be. Currently, I can get the control with jQuery using `$ctrl = $('[id$='12345']');`, but this is dirty because it would get any control that has '123456' in its id.

So, back to the original question: how do I get my ClientIds set automatically for my panels in my custom TableCells?

Edit: Code added

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
    }
```

Code in the method that adds the controls to the custom TableCell:

```
        Panel remainingTextPanel = new Panel();
        remainingTextPanel.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        remainingTextPanel.Style["display"] = "none";
        LiteralControl remainingText = new LiteralControl(myText.Substring(initialStringLength, myText.Length - initialStringLength));
        remainingTextPanel.Controls.Add(remainingText);
        this.Controls.Add(remainingTextPanel);

 Panel linkBtnPanel = new Panel(); 
        LinkButton lnkBtn = new LinkButton() {Text = "...", OnClientClick = "toggleDynamicText('" + remainingTextPanel.ID + "'); return false;" };
        lnkBtn.Font.Bold = true;
        linkBtnPanel.Controls.Add(lnkBtn);
        this.Controls.Add(linkBtnPanel);
```

And the JS Code:

```
function toggleDynamicText(id) {
$ctrl = $('[id$=' + id + ']');
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $ctrl.toggle(1000);
});
```

}

Comment: When ClientIDMode is static it will NOT add "MainContent_" to your IDs.  That's why it's called static, because it doesn't change the ID you assign it.

Comment: I think it does because that's what Firebug displays on client side. 
I set the ClientIDMode to static in Page_Load and then manually set the "ID" properties of my controls to a random string. And on client side, the "MainContent" part is added, for what reason ever.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: The Version is .NET 4.5.
I think the most important question is why my custom table cells (and the controls added to them) don't get any ClientIds assigned when they are dynamically added to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code it's difficult to say what's going on but to access your controls using jQuery you can do the following:

```
$("#<%=myElement.ClientID%>")
```

This way it doesn't matter what .NET assigns as the ID.

Comment: The whole point of this thread is that the "myElement.ClientID" is not set (as it should be)...

Comment: The ID property of the controls will not be automatically set, you have to set it.  Once you do that, then the ClientID property should also be set.

Comment: Maybe if you showed a few lines of your code then i might be able to help you better.  Add them to your original post.

Comment: Done.
I haven't tried yet if the ClientId is set after I set the ID field; this might be the problem after all.

Comment: I have tried this now, the problem still exists. Even if I set the ClientIDMode to the default setting (AutoID) and assign values to the "ID" property of a control, the ClientID still is empty. On client side, the ids look something like "MainContent_<myManualId>".

Comment: These two might help: 
[Question1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359135/asp-net-client-ids-not-being-generated-for-loaded-control) [Question2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481182/wrong-clientid-for-dynamically-added-child-control)